# Django many-to-many relationship gives "IntegrityError: could not create unique index"

Tags: django, django-models

I don't know much about Django. I'm taking over a project that was started by another developer.

I have two models, in two apps:

```
crawler/Publisher

search/Collection
```

In the database, we've been collecting some data about publishers, such as:

name

address

website

phone number

Collection has a relationship to Users. The users can create their own collections, and add publisher data to those collections. If they want to gather publishers who focus on medicine, they can create a collection called "medicine."

I added this line to crawler/Publisher:

```
# publishers -> collections                                                                                                                      
search_collection = models.ManyToManyField('search.SearchCollection', through='search.SearchPublisherCollection')
```

Then I run:

```
 python manage.py make migrations


 python manage.py migrate

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "crawler_publisher_website_145c5f8f_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (website)=(https://brandenbooks.com) is duplicated.
```

It's true that we have some duplicate data, but why does Django care? I don't care. How do I make this error go away? And why is Django creating an index on the website field?

Comment: What is your complete model? fields and attributes? meta class etc.

Comment: My guess is that when you inherited the application the models did not match the migration history. So when you run `makemigrations` you're getting a migration with all those differences, not just the one due to your change. Look at the generated migration and see what operation is causing the error. Then see if indeed there is a unique index on the associated model. In any case, to get help here you'll need to post the models and the migration.